# Laravel - A show can have multiple providers

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

So I am trying to figure a solution to this but not sure exactly how to do this. I have a table that stores all the shows that happen. In a given show I can have multiple providers attend that show. A provider could also attend many shows as well. So how do I store this in the DB and do the eloquent relationship?

Show Schema

```
Schema::create('shows', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
  $table->dateTime('airDate');
  $table->string('podcastUrl')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Provider Schema

```
Schema::create('providers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('shortName')->nullable();
  $table->string('image')->nullable();
  $table->string('social')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Would I store the provider_id in the shows schema?

**Update 1**

So I created a new migration for a pivot table

```
Schema::create('provider_show', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned()->index();
   $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->integer('show_id')->unsigned()->index();
   $table->foreign('show_id')->references('id')->on('shows')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->primary(['provider_id', 'show_id']);
});
```

Then in the show model I created the following

```
public function providers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Provider::class);
}
```

Now when I am saving a new show I added a multiselect to select the providers I want

```
$show = new Show;
$show->name = $request->name;
$show->number = $request->number;
$show->airDate = $request->airDate;
$show->podcastUrl = $request->podcastUrl;
$show->providers()->attach($request->providerList);

$show->save();

Session::flash('message', "Created Successfully!");

return back();
```

Then when I save I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: provider_show.show_id (SQL: insert into "provider_show" ("provider_id", "show_id") select 1 as "provider_id", as "show_id" union all select 2 as "provider_id", as "show_id")
```

Comment: So I am thinking that this could be done with Many To Many but not sure what needs to be in the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `provider_show` migration which will act as your pivot table.
This table would contain both `provider_id` and `show_id` which will provide the many-to-many relationship between those entities.

Then on your `Provider` model you can provide a `shows()` method which returns a `BelongsToMany` relationship.

```
// In your Provider model
public function shows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Show');
}
```

Note that Laravel by default looks for a pivot table name based alphabetically on the two relationships.

You can also add the inverse on your `Show` model by providing a `providers()` method that also returns a BelongsToMany relationship.

Comment: So I did this and then I got the following error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: provider_show.show_id (SQL: insert into "provider_show" ("provider_id", "show_id") select 1 as "provider_id", as "show_id" union all select 2 as "provider_id", as "show_id")

Comment: Do I need to add a model for provider_show and set the fillable?

Comment: What an idiot. The problem is there was not id yet on the $show variable. So I was getting error because of that. I just moved the attach after the save happens and it worked

Comment: itsmejodie, so in the providers view I can see all the shows, but in the shows I cannot see the providers. Any thoughts to why?